# What does this key code qualifier mean?

Tags: kernel, usb-drive, scsi

I know that in general this means that I have a "bad disk".  But I'm after a more specific reason for why I am getting these messages from the kernel:

```
sd 15:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
sd 15:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
sd 15:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=0x10 driverbyte=0x08
sd 15:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
sd 15:0:0:0: [sda]  ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0xc
sd 15:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
```

I've had a bit of a search and I see that 0x3 sense key means "Medium error" and ASC=0x11 means "Read error".  But it is still a mystery as to what the ASCQ=0xc means.

The device is a bus powered USB drive which reports its model as "TOSHIBA MQ01ABB200"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SCSI2-Draft standard (the only one I have that isn't a PDF):

```
Table D.1  (continued)
+=============================================================================+
|           D - DIRECT ACCESS DEVICE                                          |
|           .  .W - WRITE ONCE READ MULTIPLE DEVICE                           |
|           .  .  .O - OPTICAL MEMORY DEVICE                                  |
|           .  .  .  .                                                        |
| ASC ASCQ  DTLPWRSOMC  DESCRIPTION                                           |
| --- ----              ----------------------------------------------------- |
|  11  0C   D   W  O    UNRECOVERED READ ERROR - RECOMMEND REWRITE THE DATA   |
```

(obviously, that's not the entire table D.1)

Comment: FWIW, www.t10.org lets you download the most recent drafts of most all of their standards. www.t13.or for ATA standards, too.

Comment: "Optical memory device"?  Not sure what that means in this context.  This is a rotating disk device.

Comment: SCSI is *very* old.  Back in the day, there were optical drives. (one was the main drive in the NeXT cube) [think CD/DVD/Bluray these days]

Comment: The interesting one is the "W"... *write **once*** cannot be rewritten.

Comment: Well, that's even more mysterious.  This is definitely a multiple write device.  Also, it's strange advise to rewrite data onto a write once device.

Comment: HDDs/SSDs are classified as "Direct Access Device" and this error code is perfectly valid for them. It is likely the data is gone in such a case but the location itself can be used by writing over it.